# Tab management like in Chrome App

Tags: android

I want to manage my tabs/pages like in Chrome. I mean there will be a square icon in the actionbar which is showing the number of opened tabs/pages and If I click this, another activity or fragment will be open which includes the list of opened tabs/pages.

My first question is; will those pages/tabs must be fragments or activity? Is there a best practice? They must be always alive and the user should be able to open it whenever he wants.

And the second; I could not find any tutorial about this design. Can you suggest any?